# Resident Identity Provider Error in IDS 5.2 and API Manager 2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

### The Problem

We are currently working on our cluster with a API Manager, gateway worker, and identity server. We been follow these documents [WSO2 Clustering](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+the+Key+Manager+in+WSO2+API+Manager). When we tried to work on the basic sign-on with resident provider we would get these errors.

[image: carbon GUI error]

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-12-19 16:37:58,820] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.ui.client.IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient} -  Error in retrieving the list of Resident Identity Providers 
org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.stub.IdentityProviderMgtServiceIdentityProviderManagementExceptionException: IdentityProviderMgtServiceIdentityProviderManagementExceptionException 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.stub.IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub.updateResidentIdP(IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub.java:2217)
at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.ui.client.IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient.updateResidentIdP(IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient.java:103)
at org.apache.jsp.idpmgt.idp_002dmgt_002dedit_002dfinish_002dlocal_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(idp_002dmgt_002dedit_002dfinish_002dlocal_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:204)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)


TID: [-1234] [] [2016-12-19 16:37:58,812] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManager} -  Error while updating ResidentIdP in tenantDomain : carbon.super 
org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManagementException: Cannot find authenticator : openidconnect
        at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.IdPManagementDAO.getAuthenticatorIdentifier(IdPManagementDAO.java:2574)
        at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.IdPManagementDAO.updateFederatedAuthenticatorConfig(IdPManagementDAO.java:388)
        at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.IdPManagementDAO.updateFederatedAuthenticatorConfigs(IdPManagementDAO.java:351)
        at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.IdPManagementDAO.updateIdP(IdPManagementDAO.java:1719)
        at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO.updateIdP(CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO.java:297)
        at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManager.updateResidentIdP(IdentityProviderManager.java:697)
        at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManagementService.updateResidentIdP(IdentityProviderManagementService.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.stub.IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub.updateResidentIdP(IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub.java:2206)
        at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.ui.client.IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient.updateResidentIdP(IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient.java:103)
        at org.apache.jsp.idpmgt.idp_002dmgt_002dedit_002dfinish_002dlocal_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(idp_002dmgt_002dedit_002dfinish_002dlocal_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:204)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
```

### Possible solution

When started with a clean install, before any really configuration, we were able to update the resident provider fine. As soon we tried to connect the products (API Manager, Identity Server) together we start to get this error. We think it may have something to do with our database setup. When we were using the default built-in database it works. We seem to be stuck, I'm not even sure how to or where to start troubleshooting this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so for everyone with the same problem:
The table is IDP_AUTHENTICATOR if you use for example the WSO2 MySQL DB.

```
INSERT INTO `IDP_AUTHENTICATOR` (`TENANT_ID`, `IDP_ID`, `NAME`, `IS_ENABLED`) VALUES ('-1234', '1', 'openidconnect', '0');
```

It's quite a coincidence that I had the same problem as Bryan on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was when either the API Manager or Identity Server were creating the database tables, it didn't create one row in one of the Authentication tables, more specifically it wasn't creating the openID row. So what you can do is compare your database to the H2 embedded database to see if all the tables are being created in the right way.